# allow only unique selection of dropdown

Tags: php, ajax

I've three drop downs as product attribute. Color, Size, and Brand. Now if i select color as pink brand as raymond, size as L and press add button. I am appending one div with the combination of pink, raymond and size L. User can select multiple combinations. My question is how to restrict user to select only unique values. For example if user has selected Pink,Raymond,L and if user is selecting this combination again, at that time an alert should be thrown asking user to select other combination. I've tried to do it like every time when user making selection i am inserting the selected values in hidden field and on add button click i am checking if that value is there in that hidden field or not. It is working for one time but not for multiple time.

Comment: Show some codes,what you have tried so far.

Comment: store data in array as strings for easy checking, on each selection concatenate the values of the three select elements, so you'll get "Pink,Raymond,L". on each select do a check against this array whether item already exists, if so alert whatever.

Comment: i'd done it using jquery given below
var vld = true;
$('.attr_singname :selected').each(function(i,val){
            var vl = $(this).val();
            var elems = $('.attrb_container').find('.child[myattr='+vl+']');
            var length = elems.length;
            if(length == 0){
                vld = false;
            }
});
if(vld == false){ //execute ajax}
else{alert("already exist"); }

Comment: Just disable the selected value per dropdown. In that case you will never have the combination already selected